Outside unit won't engage
Friday night our AC quit working, the thermostats seem to be fine but when you initially turn it on "cool on" blinks for a little bit then goes away. Outside unit still doesn't engage. I've replaced the filters, cleaned the connecters on the unit outside, did a reset on the module and did maximum cold on the thermostat to no avail. I am in no way an expert on this, but having ac would be nice again without the expense of hiring someone. All I know information wise is the unit is American standard (built in 07) and the control module is NCM-300. also as pictured below, the status light blinks

Might be nice, probably not going to happen, though. 17 year old unit, plenty of possible failures, most of which take a licensed refrigeration tech to cure. The traditional approach of blindly throwing money at parts without any diagnosis is to throw new capacitors at it which helps if the problem is bad capacitors, but not if it isn't. Common enough to have the sort of failures that require replacing the whole system at that age.

Please [edit] to include brand/model of all hardware involved.

Small possibility it is the thermostat. That depends on whether "cool on blinks" is normal (i.e., to indicate start of cooling) or abnormal (i.e., should stay "cool on" the entire time). It should be possible to jumper the appropriate wires going into the thermostat to test, but the procedure will vary depending on the thermostat type. Assuming it is not the thermostat, one easy answer would be the start capacitor, but where that is on your unit and how easy/hard to replace is a big unknown. Model #s (thermostat and A/C) may help.

This is common if the condensation line is clogged.  Many systems have a float or other sensor that will not allow the unit to run if the line is full of water.  Sometimes these sensors simply fail and the unit will not run.

Also, there is no "as pictured below".
